# Consuming .NET Assembly in Classic ASP

Tags: c#, .net, dll, paypal, asp-classic

I have a classic asp site that needs to consume a .NET assembly. I have written a dll library that is COM-visible and the project is using a reference to a Paypal-SDK library. I have been successfully able to create the dll and consume it in a classic asp web page on my Windows 10 development machine. When I copy the web application to a Windows 2012 running IIS 7.x I get the following error

> nDataConsulting.PaypalStub error '80070002'
>   Could not load file or assembly 'PayPal, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, ?>PublicKeyToken=5b4afc1ccaef40fb' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot >find the file specified.

The COM visible assembly is using the Paypal.dll SDK which I believe it cannot find on the Windows 2012 server. I have tried placing the dll in the application BIN folder, tried regsvr32 etc but I have not been able to make my dll find the dependent dll. Kindly help me resolve this issue as this is a major show stopper right now

Answer (score 0):

There is a program called Dependency Walker which shows basic information about a DLL, such as its methods, and also lists the dependents DLLs.

It was answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7378982/8419161

If you find any related DLLs, you must include them along with the Paypal one.